# Piranha CMS Manager Login Session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, piranha-cms

I would like to know how to check if the user is currently logged in the Manager Area. How could I check this? Thanks.

I want to create something like:

```
    If(Session["Manager"] != null)
       bool IsManagerIn = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in permissions, check the docs here:

http://piranhacms.org/docs/api-reference/permissions

For example you could check if the current user is an Admin with:

```
if (User.HasAccess("ADMIN"))
  DoSomething();
```

Regards

/ Håkan